# Silverlight 5 mediaelement won't play or even load mp4 (x264, mp3)

Tags: silverlight-5.0, h.264, vlc, libvlc

Hi I've captured audio video record (from my C920 webcam) with VLC and I would like to play that video in Silverlight 5 mediaelement. I'm not sure what is wrong but Silverlight will not play my mp4 I believe the problem is with video because when I've demuxed mp4 to separate audio and video files only video did not play.

I can play many other mp4 (h264) video files without any problem.

Here is a link to the recorded video http://www.ulozto.net/x43rkFeW/camera-mp4

and here is the info about mp4 from media info:

```
General
Complete name                            : C:\Users\____\Documents\_Camera.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 918 KiB
Duration                                 : 15s 170ms
Overall bit rate                         : 496 Kbps
Encoded date                             : UTC 2013-09-07 20:53:33
Tagged date                              : UTC 2013-09-07 20:53:33
Writing application                      : vlc 2.0.8 stream output

Video
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3.0
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 15s 106ms
Source duration                          : 15s 138ms
Bit rate                                 : 437 Kbps
Width                                    : 640 pixels
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate                               : 30.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.047
Stream size                              : 665 KiB (72%)
Source stream size                       : 665 KiB (72%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2013-09-07 20:53:33
Tagged date                              : UTC 2013-09-07 20:53:33
mdhd_Duration                            : 15106

Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 3
Mode                                     : Joint stereo
Mode extension                           : MS Stereo
Codec ID                                 : 6B
Duration                                 : 15s 170ms
Source duration                          : 15s 196ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 3 344 Mbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 238 KiB (26%)
Source stream size                       : 238 KiB (26%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2013-09-07 20:53:33
Tagged date                              : UTC 2013-09-07 20:53:33
mdhd_Duration                            : 15170
```

Thank you very much for any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because mp3 is not supported as an audio codec you need to use AAC-LC, HE-AAC v1 (AAC+), HE-AAC v2 (eAAC+), MPEG-4 Part 2* instead.

see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)